# service in android

Tags: android

I want to include a new service related to mediaserver in my android device.

I tried making changes to the mediaserver and pushing it into the device.
   When i compiled and pushed into the device, the device did not boot. My logcat showed "MediaPlayer is not published.. waiting...". 
   When i checked running the service from the shell it showed, "link_image[1995]: failed to link mediaserver CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE"

I removed the changes from mediaserver and tried to push the exe into the device. It showed the same problem but when i pushed the mediaserver exe(took backup fearing stuffs like this would happen. .:( )the device boots properly.

I created a new service and modified init.rc to run the new service but it does not the start the service. Instead it shows CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE.

I tried to figure out the prob but the only difference I could find was the chmod to 777 and chown to shell. Even after that it is not booting.. :( If this is solved I think I will be able to make changes to mediaserver. Someone help me find out a solution..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was there were lot of dependencies in the library .so files. After removing all the dependencies, the application worked.. :):)